# Java reading txt file into tree data structure

Tags: java

I need help in implementing tree structure, I created the add child function that adds data to tree but there seems to be a problem while adding the child.

What I want the tree to look like:

```
                 Date
            /      |      \
           /       |        \
         /         |         \
       /           |           \
  20160101     20160102     20160103
    /               |       |        \
 12:00           13:00    12:00      13:00
 /    \           /   \     |       /    \
Here  There     Here There Here Here     There
```

example txt file:

```
Date,Time,Location
20160101,12:00,Here
20160101,12:00,There
20160102,13:00,Here
20160102,13:00,There
20160103,12:00, Here
20160103,13:00, Here
20160103,13:00, There
```

The output for the date seems fine, it shows 2 dates since I don't want the same date to show up twice but the time and location is wrong.

EXPECTED:

```
20160101
12:00
Here
There
20160102
13:00
Here
There
20160103
12:00
Here
13:00
Here
There
```

ACTUAL:

```
20160101
12:00
Here
There
13:00
Here
There
20160102
12:00
Here
There
13:00
Here
There
20160103
12:00
Here
There
13:00
Here
There
```

I appreciate any help or feedback for my code.

```
public class Tree {
    List<Tree> children = new ArrayList<Tree>();
    Tree parent = null;
    String data = null;

    public Tree(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Tree(String data, Tree parent){
        this.data = data;
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public void addChild(String data) {
        Tree child = new Tree(data);
        child.parent = this;
        Boolean match = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < this.children.size(); i++) {
            if (this.children.get(i).data.equals(child.data)) {
                match = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!match) {
            this.children.add(child);
        }
    }

    public void addChild(Tree child) {
        Boolean match = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < this.children.size(); i++) {
            if (this.children.get(i).data.equals(child.data)) {
                match = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!match) {
            this.children.add(child);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        Scanner scanFile = new Scanner(new File("example.txt"));
        String line = "";
        line = scanFile.nextLine();
        Tree parentNode = new Tree(line.split(",")[0]);
        Tree dateNode = new Tree(null, parentNode);
        Tree timeNode = new Tree(null, dateNode);
        Tree locationNode = new Tree(null, timeNode);
        System.out.println(parentNode.data);

        while(scanFile.hasNext()) {
            line = scanFile.nextLine();

            timeNode.addChild(line.split(",")[2]);
            dateNode.addChild(line.split(",")[1]);
            parentNode.addChild(line.split(",")[0]);
        }
        scanFile.close();



        for(int i =0; i < parentNode.children.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(parentNode.children.get(i).data);
            for(int j = 0; j < dateNode.children.size(); j++) {
                System.out.println(dateNode.children.get(j).data);
                for(int k = 0; k < timeNode.children.size(); k++) {
                    System.out.println(timeNode.children.get(k).data);
            }
    }

    long endTime = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("Time taken: " + (endTime - startTime) / 1E9 + "s");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your tree logic supposed to be? Your printing just prints the same data from `dateNode` and `timeNode` over and over again for each element of `parentNode`.

Comment: it's supposed to print all children data from `timeNode` and all children data from `dateNode` for each element of `parentNode`, the problem is the size of `dateNode.children` and `timeNode.children` is only 1

Comment: Again, the problem is that the tree structure does not make sense (you haven't explained what tree you were supposed to build), and that your printing is wrong. You are not assigning anything to `timeNode` and `dateNode` after you finish scanning, so they keep having the last value that you scanned. You should [edit] the question, explain what the logic of the tree is supposed to be. It's important that you learn to use a debugger so that you can follow your program step by step, and see what the nodes really contain.

Comment: edited, tried changing the code and it seems now each children of `dateNode` has both times and both locations for each time

Comment: Sorry, but something is still wrong here. The code won't compile because it has calls to `addChild` with a `String` parameter, and your `addChild` method only accepts a `Tree`. So either there is a method you have not shown, or this is not the real code. Make sure the code is the exact code that produces the output you have written about.

Answer (score -1):

Try these:

```
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String,Map<String,List<String>>> tree = new TreeMap<String,Map<String,List<String>>>();

    for(int i=0;i<lines.size();i++){

        String[] parts = lines.get(i).split(",");

        if(!tree.containsKey(parts[0])){
            tree.put(parts[0],new TreeMap<String,List<String>>());
        }

        Map<String,List<String>> tree2 = tree.get(parts[0]);

        if(!tree.containsKey(parts[1])){
            tree2.put(parts[1],new ArrayList<String>());
        }

        List<String> tree3 = tree2.get(parts[1]);

        if(!tree3.contains(parts[2])){
            tree3.add(parts[2]);
        }

    }
```